# how to echo/display the custom field value of a specific custom field name?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried this code:

> ```
>         <?php 
>             query_posts(array(
>             'meta_key' => 'custom_cat',
>             'meta_value' => 'creative',
>             'post_type' => 'page'
>         ));
>             echo '<ul id="creative_services" class="clearfix row">';
>             if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
>                     echo '<li class="col-md-3">';
>                     echo '<a class="popover-dismiss" data-toggle="popover" title="';
>                     echo $post->post_title;
>                     echo '" data-placement="bottom" data-content="';
>                     echo $post->post_content;
>                     echo '"><i class="';
>                     get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fa_icon' );
>                     echo '"></i></a>';
>                     echo '<h3>';
>                     the_title();
>                     echo '</h3>';
>              endwhile; 
>             echo '</ul>';
>             wp_reset_query(); ?>
> ```

to display the custom field value as a class name, but the value is not displaying. Please help me find the problem or solution to display the custom field value as class name. I'm having hard time to debug this codes because i'm not a programmer, i'm a designer, still in the process of exploring wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `echo` before `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fa_icon' );`
so it would be:

```
<?php 
        query_posts(array(
        'meta_key' => 'custom_cat',
        'meta_value' => 'creative',
        'post_type' => 'page'
    ));
        echo '<ul id="creative_services" class="clearfix row">';
        if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                echo '<li class="col-md-3">';
                echo '<a class="popover-dismiss" data-toggle="popover" title="';
                echo $post->post_title;
                echo '" data-placement="bottom" data-content="';
                echo $post->post_content;
                echo '"><i class="';
                echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fa_icon' );
                echo '"></i></a>';
                echo '<h3>';
                the_title();
                echo '</h3>';
         endwhile; 
        echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
```